# show $\alpha=t^{1/p}$ is not separable over $F.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I had this question in my exam ,but don't know how to proceed:

> Let $F=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z(t)$ where $t$ is indeterminate. Then show $\alpha=t^{1/p}$ is not separable over $F.$

What I know is that an element is called separable over $F$ if it is algebraic over $F$ and its minimal polynomial over $F$ is a separable polynomial.

Kindly help how to start with ...

Comment: The minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ is $X^p-t$, an inseparable polynomial.

Comment: Thanks I got it. as F is of characteristic $p$ . thus, if $X^p -t$ separable then its derivative can't be $0$ ,but here it is $0$ . Hence ,it has to be inseparable .

Comment: Also: in $F(\alpha)$ we have: $X^p - t = (X - \alpha)^p$, since $F$ (and thus $F(\alpha)$) has characteristic $p$.